# How to make HTML configurable table dynamic

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I am sending some HTML Body in Email as below :-

```
string MessageBody = string.Empty;
                MessageBody += "-------------------DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL-----------------";
                MessageBody += "<br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  THIS IS AN AUTO GENERATED EMAIL ";
                MessageBody += "<br/><br/>Server IP : " + IPOfServer;
                MessageBody += "<br/>Server Time : " + ServerUTCDateTime + "<br/>";
                foreach (var item in lstEmailBody)
                {
                    string ErrorInService = (item.pServiceName == "" ? "Preprocessing" : item.pServiceName);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.pFileID))
                        MessageBody += "<br/>Error Details For FileID " + item.pFileID + "<br/>";
                    else
                        MessageBody += "<br/>";
                    MessageBody += @"<table border=1>   
                                        <tr>
                                             <td> Service Name </td> 
                                             <td> " + ErrorInService + @"</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                             <td> Error Name </td> 
                                             <td> " +item.pErrorMessage+@" </td>
                                        <tr>
                                  </table><br/><br/>";
                }
```

I want to make all the email body configurable.

For this I am creating one HTML file in which I am putting all these tags and reading the HTML text in c# function and replacing the necessary values.

```
Eg. string MessageBody = GetBodyFromHTMLTemplate();

MessageBody= MessageBody.Replace("#serverIP",IPOfServer);
```

But I am in confusion , How can I dynamically create tables as done above in `foreach loop`

In the template I will get only one table as:-

```
<table border=1>   
 <tr>
   <td> Service Name </td> 
   <td> #ServiceName</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td> Error Name </td> 
   <td> #Error Message </td>
 </tr>
</table><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Create your table with a foreach and store the result in a variable then, when your foreach is done, just append your table code

Comment: I dont want to generate table through C# code, It should be in sample Template and c# should fetch it